# str.contains doesn't find partial matches

Tags: pandas, string, contains

In a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5'],
                   'colB': ['Black cat', 'Black mouse', 'Black_A cat', 'Black cat', 'White_A mouse']})
```

I want to find all the lines where `colB` contains `Black cat`. My command

`df[df['colB'].str.contains('Black cat', na=False)]`

allows to find only

```
colA    colB
0   id1 Black cat
3   id4 Black cat
```

while I expect this:

```
    colA    colB
0   id1 Black cat
2   id3 Black_A cat
3   id4 Black cat
```

What is wrong with partial matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's `partial match` in your case? `contains` is to find exact substrings, so `Black A cat` wouldn't match `Black cat`. If you expect optional characters in between `Black` and `cat` you should specify that in the pattern:

```
df[df['colB'].str.contains('Black.*cat', na=False)]
#                                ^ this
```

Output:

```
  colA         colB
0  id1    Black cat
2  id3  Black_A cat
3  id4    Black cat
```